# Words get cut of in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, padding, margins

I'm stuck with a small problem in my listview. I tried several things like adding padding or changing the margins. But this didn't fix my problem.
Words keep getting cut of in the last rule.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/violationstitlebar"

        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/resTaskviolPos"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/resTaskviolDescriptionNLB"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/resTaskDescriptionFRB" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/resTaskviolBLS"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/resTaskviolRepeat"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

            />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/tvViolListPosition"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/tvViolListDescription"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="4"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col3"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/ibViolListEditDesc"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/tvViolListDescriptionFRB"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col5"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/ibViolListEditDescFRB"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spViolListConclusion"
            style="?android:dropDownSpinnerStyle"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/etViolListCounter"
            android:inputType="number"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/violation_list_col8"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/ibViolListDelete"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

kind regards,

Tim

Comment: Can you provide xml of your item please ?

Comment: Show your XML. And trim the image too

Comment: You can put textView in scrollview or you can use maxLines for TextView.

Comment: XML added and picture trimmed :)

Answer (score 0):

give some limitaion to charaters ,while adding the content of your NLB

maxlines, minimum lines

```
<EditText
                            android:id="@+id/AddressEdittext"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/retangle_shape"
                            android:gravity="top|left"
                            android:hint="Type  Here..."
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:lines="5"
                            android:maxLines="10"
                            android:minLines="5"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical" >
                        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this property also with some padding bottom:

```
 android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

And:

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it with layout_weight attribute.

More info on layout_weight can be found on:
http://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html